# Import csv into redis Set

Tags: python, linux, redis, redis-cluster

I have a csv file which has 1million msisdn per line. I want to load that 1million msisdn in Redis Set name scrub1 with the one line Linux terminal command.

I have used the below command but it is storing in type (String).

```
cat BL_removal.csv | awk -F',' '{print " SET scrub01 \""$1"\" \n"}' | redis-cli --pipe
```

I want each msisdn in Set like this
"/scrub01/msisdn"

Can anyone help?
THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Set command is to assign a value to a String.

To add things to Set in Redis, you use command

[SADD](https://redis.io/commands/sadd)

```
cat BL_removal.csv | awk -F',' '{print " SADD scrub01 \""$1"\" \n"}' | redis-cli --pipe
```

Then you issue

```
redis-cli smembers scrub01
```

to check the result

Comment: Can you please give me a complete command. On SADD it is giving me Wrongtype error
    WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value